# Get the number of milliseconds since some date

Tags: java

How to get the number of milliseconds from October 15th 2011 1:52:34 P.M.

I can get the number of milliseconds from the current time.

```
Date date = new Date();
        long currentTime = date.getTime();
        System.out.println("Current time in long: " + currentTime);
```

Comment: no that's not an homework... I am preparing for an interview so they asked me some coding questions.. So that's what I am asking..!!

Comment: The interview question isn't particularly well posed. The original time could, in theory, be in any Time Zone, and this could make the answer vary by anything up to almost 24 hours, which is an awful lot of milliseconds!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Simpler way to get current time
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd yyyy h:mm:ss a").parse("15 2011 1:52:34 PM");
long timeElapsed = now - date.getTime(); // Here's your number of ms
```

Comment: This gives the correct answer only if the specified time is in the default TimeZone for the computer which is running the program. This *may* be what is wanted, but it should probably not be assumed without further input.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Calendar API. Then set the month, date and the time you want (October 15, 2011).
To get you started look into this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-get-time-in-milliseconds-in-java/)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;




public class TimeMilisecond {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {

      long lDateTime = new Date().getTime();
      System.out.println("Date() - Time in milliseconds: " + lDateTime);

      Calendar lCDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
      System.out.println("Calender - Time in milliseconds :" + lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis());

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse an arbitrariy date and get the difference in ms.

Answer (score 0):

Use [java.util.Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and fill it with your date information. Then use `java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` to get the number of milliseconds since epoch.